# Is conditional independence of random variables preserved under diffeomorphisms?

Tags: conditional-probability, independence

I have a general question to understand when conditional independence is preserved.

Let $(X, Y, \mathbf{Z})$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $\mathbf{Z}$ is a random vector. If $X \perp Y | \mathbf{Z}$, then under what conditions are $f(X) \perp g(Y) | h(\mathbf{Z})$ valid, where $f, g$ and $h$ are valid functions?

According to [conditional independence of functions of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762708/conditional-independence-of-functions-of-random-variables) it seems that this does not hold in general.

1. However, is it true for $f, g$ and $h$ that are diffeomorphisms?
2. What is the intuition for why it does not hold in general, but it does for diffeomorphisms?
3. What are other constraints on the functions $f, g,$ and $h$ that preserve conditional independence?

Comment: For trivial reasons it holds when $h$ is bijective and $f, g$ are arbitrary.

Comment: @Mason so in other words, as long as the mapping for Z is invertible, then f and g can be anything? Is there a proof for this lying out there, or just some illustration of why this is true vs not?

Comment: Apply the definition of conditional independence. The main reason is that if $h$ is bijective, then $\sigma(h(Z)) = \sigma(Z)$, so conditional independence given $h(Z)$ is equivalent to conditional independence given $Z$.